# Whole House Fan Emergency Shutoff / Limit Control

Tags: electrical, hvac

We are installing a whole house fan (which we already have) and would like the extra precaution of an emergency shutoff so it won’t cause extra risk of fire spread if a fire occurs (due to it causing airflow). We believe the right device is a snap disc control or a limit control like these sold at Grainger: https://www.grainger.com/category/hvac-and-refrigeration/hvac-controls-and-thermostats/ignition-control-components/fan-and-limit-controls?filters=webParentSkuKey&webParentSkuKey=WP8497456%7CWP8497715

However, there are a lot of options. We have guessed that we at least need the open temperature to be higher than the close temperature for this application and likely want an automatic reset instead of manual.

The next questions are:

- What temperature should it open at to provide safety without too many false alarms?
- Where does this device get mounted? In the attic near the fan, in the wall near the controls, or maybe in the attic not near the fan?
- What are they mounted on/in since they seem to just have quick connect terminals but mounting inside a box would seem to defeat some of the purpose of temperature sensing?
- Do we want a snap disc control or limit control (if there is any difference, on that sales page or mostly seems to be a divide between brand of device).

Comment: Are you sure you want this to be heat based, instead of being triggered off your smoke detectors?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel wouldn't you want it running most when a smoke detector is going off? 90%+ of smoke detector beeps are not in an actual emergency but in a smoky/stinky kitchen situation. If you could wait for input from 2+ smoke detectors, that would be really good, but that might be a bit complex for many folks...

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel We do have a 3-wire smoke detector system (Kidde brand, separate CO and dual-sensor smoke) and those wires pass next to the whole house fan, but are on a different circuit. It seems the Kidde a relay (SM120X) which could be used for this, although I would have to think through how to get that wired properly.

Comment: I would have thought the user manual for such devices can explain how to pick a sensible temperature limit.   BTW, you want to make sure whatever you choose can handle the current drawn by the fan, not just the voltage.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft We have no user manual for the fan itself. But we do have information about it including the current required (max 6.5 amps). It will be on its own 15 amp circuit. We don't want it on the circuit with the fire alarms (which also have lights, 2 ceiling fans, and outlets). Is there a way to bridge the relay from one circuit to another? On the other hand, I guess the fire alarm system could be moved over to the whole house fan circuit.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I did find a possible piece of information about the cutoff though. I found a product catalog (https://www.tpicorp.com/uploads/2/2/3/3/22337256/tpi_electrical_products.pdf) with a newer version of the fan in it (BD30-2-WHS). Just below the fan product they also sell a "SP Close on rise" part that has a range of 80°-130°F.

Comment: @thaimin the relay can certainly control a different circuit than the smoke detectors are on

Comment: Yeah, I was re-reading its manual, and although all of the examples have both on the same circuit, the blue common contact wire can be put on a separate circuit. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using a device designed specifically for your concern.  Here's an ["attic fan fire safety switch" (from Home Depot)](https://www.homedepot.com/p/SolarAtticFan-Fire-Safety-Cut-Off-Switch-FSCS-SS/203807520). No, it's not resettable.  No, you don't want to "reset" your fan automatically when there is/was a fire in the house.

EDIT: a resettable thermostat switch, such as [these](https://www.zoro.com/kbmt/whole-house-fan-control-switch/) are designed to turn on the fan when the house gets too warm, and shut off when the house cools.   Use in series with the fire-safety fuse.

Comment: +1 Exactly the right item! Something similar is part of my Kitchenaid oven - on top where it should never get that hot (but one time it did...) and simply melts/burns out at that temperature and you have to replace it. 228F is hot enough that no normal house (even in Arizona, etc.) will get that hot but low enough to (hopefully) help cut down on problems if there is a fire.

Comment: Embedded the device name in the answer so future readers will know what to look for when HD reorganizes their web site or quits carrying that brand.

Comment: A whole house fan is not an attic fan though... but I did take part of your advice and we are going with a **manual** reset snap disk controller which cuts off at 135 F. From what I can find 130 F is the hottest attics should get before doing damage to other parts of the attic. Also, the official product from the fan creator goes to 130 F.